# Are you old enough to drink? Python problem

Tags: python-3.x, shortcode

I’m trying to write a function that tells the user if they are old enough to drink.

Whenever I run what I wrote it says there is a syntax error in line 3 where it says “If age> 20: ”. What am I doing wrong:

```
age = int(input("how old are you?")

if age > 20:
    print("You're old enough to drink")
else:
    print("Go drink some apple juice")
```

Comment: you need to close `int(` paranthesis

Comment: Consider using a syntax aware editor (like vim).  Invalid syntax will essentially be highlighted.  I use PyCharm CE - it's free and works great.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a bracket `age = int(input("how old are you?"))`

Answer (score 1):

`age = int(input("how old are you?")`< You are missing a ) at the end of the line.